# MD5 file hash functions in R returning different values?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

An MD5 hash should return the same value irrespective of who performs the hash calculation and where.

Yet using three different methods on the same file, we see three different answers (!?).

[Here](https://collidr-api.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/pfd.RDS)'s the file.

The MD5 hash [according to Amazon Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817303/aws-service-to-verify-data-integrity-of-file-in-s3-via-checksum/59833028#59833028) is:

```
library(dplyr)
"https://collidr-api.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/pfd.RDS" %>% curlGetHeaders %>% .[6] %>% trimws %>% 
  strsplit(., "ETag: ") %>% .[[1]] %>% .[2] %>% 
  { substr(., 2, nchar(.)) } %>% { substr(., 1, nchar(.) - 1)}
# "a921f713fbd730a51814fb6602048c16"
```

The MD5 hash [using the `digest` library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21686808) is

```
library(digest)
digest("Downloads/pfd.RDS", algo=c("md5"))
# "2b049aba0269e46d35780c3e7d29a916"
```

And the MD5 hash [using `openssl` library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526275/) is

```
library(openssl)
md5("Downloads/pfd.RDS")
# "8ceabf9bdd146ed12ba89533cd593d12"
```

I can't explain this. I expected all three values to be the same since they're all applying the same algorithm (MD5) to the same file, yet all 3 are different.

#### Question

Why aren't the hash values the same irrespective of the method used to generate the MD5 hash of the file, and most importantly, how do I calculate the hash in R such that it matches the MD5 hash provided by AWS (i.e .`a921f713fbd730a51814fb6602048c16`)?

#### UPDATE

In mac terminal `md5 Downloads/pfd.RDS` returns `a921f713fbd730a51814fb6602048c16` (consistent with the AWS value). It's still not clear why `digest::digest()` and `openssl::md5()` values are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hash the contents of the file at that path, you need to tell each of the functions that. Try

```
digest("Downloads/pfd.RDS", file=TRUE, algo="md5")
```

and

```
md5(file("Downloads/pfd.RDS", open="rb"))
```

otherwise you are hashing the path name itself.

These return the same values in the simple case of

```
cat("hello", file="hello.txt")
digest("hello.txt", file=TRUE, algo="md5")
# [1] "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592"
md5(file("hello.txt", open="rb"))
# md5 5d:41:40:2a:bc:4b:2a:76:b9:71:9d:91:10:17:c5:92
```

Comment: `digest("Downloads/pfd.RDS", file=TRUE, algo="md5")` returns `# [1] "a921f713fbd730a51814fb6602048c16"` (expected), but `md5(file("Downloads/pfd.RDS"))` returns `md5 3a:b7:0d:89:31:89:8b:dd:c3:8b:65:04:6c:ae:6a:25`

Comment: You are running both these commands in the exact same R session and are getting different responses? Does the example i included return the same value for both functions?

Comment: Yes, both commands are in the exact same R session (one right after the other). Your example returns the same value for both functions.

Comment: Use `file("Downloads/pfd.RDS", open = "rb")` so the connection is opened for reading in binary mode.

Comment: @H1 awesome knowledge. How did you figure that out? (I had come to a dead end)

Comment: @user5783745 A different hash meant the file had undergone a change and the file being opened in text mode rather than binary mode was a likely candidate.